# Changing style of an element via vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
<a href="" style="right:0px">right</a>
```

I would like to change it into

```
<a href="" style="left:0px">right</a>
```

In jQuery I can do this

```
$('a').attr('style','left:0px');
```

But how can I do this in traditional javascript without using jquery?

Comment: Any reason you're not doing this in your CSS?

Comment: jQuery is JavaScript. Do you mean to ask how you can modify styles using stock JavaScript without any libraries?

Comment: The fiddle you linked seems a little irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you everyone anyway, I guess soon I'll become a js expert :-D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a'),
    l = elements.length;

while ( l-- ) elements[l].style.left = '0px';
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/236pk/

---

If you're using a modern browser, you can use this one liner:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(e => e.style.left = '0px');
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/236pk/24

Comment: You should remove the "right" style attribute as well. It's just a happy accident that `left` overrides `right` in this case. http://jsfiddle.net/236pk/1/

Answer (score -2):

JavaScript answer already there, but you tagged it jQuery, while mentioning you didn't want to use jQuery. Maybe you just don't realize how easy JavaScript is with jQuery in play, and it can be used just about anywhere you use JavaScript, with 0 bad side effects. So below is how easy it is to do this with jQuery, and with way less code.

```
$("a").css({ left: "0px", right: "" })
```

## jsFiddle

I know you showed a jQuery example, but it's not quite right, thus I'm guessing you were thinking it would be easier in JavaScript since you couldn't figure out the jQuery proper way. Just include the right in the style and set its value to an empty string and that will set you style correctly.

And just a little more, while the answer selected shows an easy way to do it, it does not account for what is in your question. Namely the a tag already having `style="right:0px;"`. If you want to make it all correct, use his formula but add one line:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a'),
    l = elements.length;

while ( l-- ) {
    elements[l].style.left = '0px';
    elements[l].style.right= ''; // here in lies the added line, it removes the previously set "right"
}
```

Comment: And also mentioned, *without using jQuery*. :-)

Comment: @Abhilash I know, but it is tagged [jQuery] and i just figured maybe he wants without because he does not yet understand how EASY jQuery makes JavaScript and that it can be used in almost any application/website using JavaScript.